# Can't connect to Oracle Autonomous Database in Sequelize

Tags: node.js, oracle, sequelize.js

I'm tying to connect to my Oracle database. Oracle database only provides connection string but Sequelize doesn't seem to work with that.

```
sequelize = new Sequelize({
    user: '<user>', 
    password: '<password>', 
    dialect: 'oracle',
    connectionString: '<connectionString>'
}})
```

Is it possible and if not can you guys recommend other alternatives?

Comment: To connect to Autonomous database, you need to use the wallet, some doc here https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/blob/main/doc/api.md

Comment: As long as you have a recent Oracle Client library you no longer always need to use a wallet to connect to ADB.  Connecting with or without a wallet is discussed in the doc, which is at [Connecting to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Databases](https://node-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#connecting-to-oracle-cloud-autonomous-databases).

Answer (score 0):

You can use **oracledb** library for connecting with oracle cloud database.

Here's the setup for connecting to oracle DB with node-oracle(oracledb).

```
const oracledb = require('oracledb');


async function run() {

  let connection;

  try {

    connection = await oracledb.getConnection({ user: "demonode", password: "XXXX", connectionString: '<connectionString>' });

    console.log("Successfully connected to Oracle Database");

    // Create a table

    await connection.execute(`begin
                                execute immediate 'drop table todoitem';
                                exception when others then if sqlcode <> -942 then raise; end if;
                              end;`);

    await connection.execute(`create table todoitem (
                                id number generated always as identity,
                                description varchar2(4000),
                                creation_ts timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp,
                                done number(1,0),
                                primary key (id))`);

    // Insert some data

    const sql = `insert into todoitem (description, done) values(:1, :2)`;

    const rows =
          [ ["Task 1", 0 ],
            ["Task 2", 0 ],
            ["Task 3", 1 ],
            ["Task 4", 0 ],
            ["Task 5", 1 ] ];

    let result = await connection.executeMany(sql, rows);

    console.log(result.rowsAffected, "Rows Inserted");

    connection.commit();

    // Now query the rows back

    result = await connection.execute(
      `select description, done from todoitem`,
      [],
      { resultSet: true, outFormat: oracledb.OUT_FORMAT_OBJECT });

    const rs = result.resultSet;
    let row;

    while ((row = await rs.getRow())) {
      if (row.DONE)
        console.log(row.DESCRIPTION, "is done");
      else
        console.log(row.DESCRIPTION, "is NOT done");
    }

    await rs.close();

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } finally {
    if (connection) {
      try {
        await connection.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

run();
```

**OR**

You can follow the steps given in the link below:

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/quickstartnodejs.html

Comment: The article https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/quickstartnodejs.html is the equivalent content for ADB.